# JRuby Rails Project with Java Code Git Repository Organization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, jruby

Any advice on Git repository organization for starting a new project on JRuby that will have a Java Server component and Ruby on Rails component? I'm guessing that I put the Java and Ruby parts in separate repositories. What would be the pros and cons of putting them in one repository versus separate ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two repositories if the development of one project does not affect the other directly (i.e. moving files from one part to the other, renaming variables, global data, or connections...).

Also, if different users will code each part is best to split them.

Thinking on releasing, does one new version of one part means a new version for the other? If the answer is no you definitely want to have different repositories.

At the end, either with a single or with two repositories, since is git you can split or join them later, though it will take your time.

Comment: I'm looking at deploying on heroku with a pom file. I suppose might be easier if everything is all together.